# CSS issue when going mobile right white margin

Tags: css

Have a problem with my CSS, when going mobile I have a margin right white that I hope make to disappear. This appear especially when starting to move the cursor on the left, the right white margin will start to appear. I have put the code in the snippet to show the result.

[image]
[image]

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */


.img-responsive {
 display:inline-block;
 max-height:100px;
 max-width:auto;
 padding-top:0;
 padding-bottom:50px;
}

section
{
 
}
.banner
{
  background:red;
  min-height:200px;
}
.banner .row
{
  text-align:center;
  margin-top:50px;
}
.banner h1
{
  color:white;
}

.social{
 width:60%;
 margin:auto;
 padding-bottom:100px;
}



/***********************************************************************
*  OPAQUE NAVBAR SECTION
***********************************************************************/
.opaque-navbar {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    height: 100px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    transition: background-color .5s ease 0s;
}

.opaque-navbar.opaque {
    background-color: #0670EB;
    height: 100px;
    transition: background-color .5s ease 0s;
}

ul.dropdown-menu {
    background-color: black;
}

<!-- navbar button-->
.navbar-btn {
    border-color: #ffffff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Montserrat,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #0670EB;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 6px 12px !important;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
.navbar-btn:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #0670EB !important;
    border-color: #FFF !important;
}

.btn-primary {
 padding-top:10px;
    border-color: #ffffff;
 background-color:#ffffff;
    font-family: Montserrat,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #0670EB;
 margin-top: 25px;
 height:40px;
}


@media (max-width: 992px) {
  body
  {
   max-width:100%;
    background:white;
  }
  .opaque-navbar {
    background-color: transparent;
    height: 60px;
    transition: background-color .5s ease 0s;
}

}

<!-- carousel-->

/* Carousel base class */






.carousel {
 max-width:100%;
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}
/* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */


.carousel-btn {
    border-color: #0670EB;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Montserrat,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 6px 12px !important;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
}
.carousel-btn:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #FFFFFF !important;
    border-color: #0670EB !important;
}
.btn-carousel {
    border-color: #ffffff;
 background-color:#0670EB;
    font-family: Montserrat,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #0670EB;
}



@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .item {
        height: auto;
    }
    .item > img {
         width: auto%;
    }
}

/* tablets */
@media (max-width: 991px) and (min-width: 768px) {
    .item {
        height: auto;
    }
    .item  > img {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

/* laptops */
@media (max-width: 1023px) and (min-width: 992px) {
    .item {
         height: auto;
    }
    .item > img {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

/* desktops */
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
    .item {
        height: 650px;
    }
    .item > img {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 769px) {
  .carousel-caption p {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
 font-size:2em;
 font-weight:400
 }
  .carousel-caption p1 {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
 font-size:3em;
 font-weight:bold
 }
 .carousel-caption {
 top:50%;
 bottom:auto;
 z-index: 50;
}
 
}

@media (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .carousel-caption p {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
 font-size:1.5em;
 font-weight:400
 }
  .carousel-caption p1 {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
 font-size:2.5em;
 font-weight:bold
 }
 .carousel-caption {
 top:45%;
 bottom:auto;
 z-index: 50;
}

}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .carousel-caption p {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
 font-size:1.2em;
 font-weight:400
 }
  .carousel-caption p1 {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
 font-size:1.5em;
 font-weight:bold
 }
 .carousel-caption {
 top:40%;
 bottom:auto;
 z-index: 50;
}
}
 

 .divider {
  margin-top:50px;
 }

/* ------ H O W  I T  W O R K S ------ */
.how-it-works-title {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight:bold;
  line-height: 18px;
  margin: 25px 0 15px;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:10px;


}

.how-it-works-subtitle {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 18px;
  margin: 25px 0 15px;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:10px;
  font-weight:lighter;
  padding-bottom:10px;

}

.how-it-works-step-icon {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
 .section-title {
 font-size: 28px;
 font-color:#4C535D;
 font-weight: bold;
 line-height: 18px;
 margin: 0;
 padding-top:50px;
 padding-bottom:60px;
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}



}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
 .section-title {
 font-size: 20px;
 font-color:#4C535D;
 font-weight: bold;
 line-height: 18px;
 margin: 0;
 padding-top:50px;
 padding-bottom:60px;
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
 
}



.section-subtitle {
 font-size: 15px;
 font-weight: normal;
 letter-spacing: 1.5px;
 margin: 10px 0 0 0;
 text-align: center;
}

.featurette-divider {

  margin: 5rem 0; /* Space out the Bootstrap <hr> more */
}

/* Thin out the marketing headings */
.featurette-heading {
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: -.05rem;
}
 .featurette-heading {
    font-size: 50px;
  }
  @media (min-width: 62em) {
  .featurette-heading {
    margin-top: 7rem;
  }
}
/* MARKETING CONTENT
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Center align the text within the three columns below the carousel */
.marketing .col-lg-4 {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}
.marketing h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
}
.marketing .col-lg-4 p {
  margin-right: .75rem;
  margin-left: .75rem;
}
.marketing-title {
 text-align:center;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #4C535D;
 padding-bottom:50px;
}

.marketing-sub {
 text-align:center;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
 font-size:30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #4C535D;
 padding-bottom:50px;
}

<!-- categories-->
.category {
padding-top: 3rem;
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
  background-color: #096;
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
 
.categoryimg {
  display:block;
    height:487px;
    max-width:100%;

}


.categorytext {
padding: 0 15px;
padding-top:12%;
font-family: Avenir;
color:#0670EB;
font-weight:bold;
background-color:white;
height:487px;
float:left;
}
.lead {
font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
color:#4C535D;
padding-right:10px;
}
 
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
 .categoryimg {
 display:block;
    height:300px;
    max-width:100%;

}

.container {
 margin:auto;
 max-width:100%;
}

.container-fluid {
 max-width:100%;
}

.categorytext {
padding: 0 15px;
padding-top:10px;
font-family: Avenir;
color:#0670EB;
font-weight:bold;
background-color:white;
height:200px;
float:left;
}
.lead {
font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
color:#4C535D;
padding-right:10px;
}
 
}





.input-group {
    margin: 20px auto;
    width: 100%;
}
input.btn.btn-lg,
input.btn.btn-lg:focus {
    outline: none;
    width: 40%;
    height: 60px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
button.btn {
 background-color:#0670EB;
 margin-left:50px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 60px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
.subscribe {
 justify-content: center; 
}


.pad0{
    padding: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.footer {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
 font-size:15px;
    color: #4C535D;
}

.license {
 text-align:center;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
 font-size:12px;
    color: #4C535D;
}


.container {
 margin:auto;
 display:block;
 max-width:100%;
}

.container-fluid {
 margin:auto;
 max-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    
<title>nibook | Share your skills and services with locals | Break the wall </title>



 <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <!-- Theme CSS -->
    <link href="css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="css/classic-10_7.css" rel="stylesheet">



</head>

<body>

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top opaque-navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navMain">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger" style="color:white;"></span>
    
  </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo_white.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navMain">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
        <a class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn" href="main/profile.html">Become nibooker</a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<!-- carousel indicators-->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
<li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>
<li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
<li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
</ol>
<!-- wrapper for slides-->
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
<div class="item active">
<img class="first-slide" src="img/bkg/3.png" alt="First slide">
<div class="container">
<div class="carousel-caption">
<p1>SHARE YOUR SKILLS AND SERVICES WITH LOCALS</p1>
<p>#BreakTheWall</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="item">
<img class="second-slide" src="img/bkg/2.png" alt="Second slide">
<div class="container">
<div class="carousel-caption">
<p1>MONETIZE YOUR SKILLS AND TALENT</p1>
<p>#BreakTheWall</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="item">
<img class="third-slide"src="img/bkg/1.png" alt="Third slide" >
<div class="container">
<div class="carousel-caption">
<p1>GET AN EXTRAORDINARY CHINA'S EXPERIENCE</p1>
<p>#BreakTheWall</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Controls -->
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" button="button" data-slide="prev" >
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" button="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<h1 class="section-title"> HOW NIBOOK WORKS</h1>
    <div class="col-sm-4"><img src="img/Profile.png" class="how-it-works-step-icon">    <h1 class="how-it-works-title">Become a Nibooker</h1>
<h2 class="how-it-works-subtitle">Create your profile and start sharing your skills and services to locals</h2></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"><img src="img/bookmark.png" class="how-it-works-step-icon"><h1 class="how-it-works-title">Get booked from locals</h1>
<h2 class="how-it-works-subtitle">Meet in your convenient place to provide your talent</h2></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"><img src="img/page.png" class="how-it-works-step-icon"><h1 class="how-it-works-title">Receive your money</h1>
<h2 class="how-it-works-subtitle">Get your money directly to your account</h2></div>
</div>
</div>


<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<h1 class="section-title"> What's skills can you provide to locals?</h1>
</div>
</div>
</div>

 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 pad0">
     <img src="img/language.png" class="categoryimg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 pad0">
     <div class="categorytext">
      <h2>LANGUAGES</h2>
      <p class="lead">Nibook is a platform where foreigners can change their frame time into money by crafting beautiful services and share them with the locals within in-person or online experiences.</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6 pad0">
     <img src="img/art.png" class="categoryimg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6 pad0">
     <div class="categorytext">
      <h2>CREATIVITY</h2>
      <p class="lead">Nibook is a platform where foreigners can change their frame time into money by crafting beautiful services and share them with the locals within in-person or online experiences.</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 pad0">
     <img src="img/dailylife.png" class="categoryimg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 pad0">
     <div class="categorytext">
      <h2>DAILY LIFE</h2>
      <p class="lead">Nibook is a platform where foreigners can change their frame time into money by crafting beautiful services and share them with the locals within in-person or online experiences.</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6 pad0">
     <img src="img/fashion.png" class="categoryimg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6 pad0">
     <div class="categorytext">
      <h2>LIFESTYLE</h2>
      <p class="lead">Nibook is a platform where foreigners can change their frame time into money by crafting beautiful services and share them with the locals within in-person or online experiences.</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div></div>

      
      <div class="container marketing">

      <!-- Three columns of text below the carousel -->
      <div class="row">
      <h1 class="marketing-title">WHERE NIBOOK IS HAPPENING</h1>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <img class="img-circle" src="img/hangzhou.png" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
          <h2 class="marketing-sub">Hangzhou</h2>
        </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <img class="img-circle" src="img/shanghai.png" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
          <h2 class="marketing-sub">Shanghai</h2>
        </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <img class="img-circle" src="img/qingdao.png" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
          <h2 class="marketing-sub">Qingdao</h2>      
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
 <div class="subscribe">
 <!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<div id="mc_embed_signup">

    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
<div class="indicates-required">Subscribe to know more!</div>
</div></div>
</div>
</div></div>
<div id="mc_embed_signupform">

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<form class="form-inline" action="http://nibook.us14.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=aa8370722661ed324627f57b5&amp;id=57f1deb3f4" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" target="_blank" novalidate>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" value="" placeholder="Enter your email" name="EMAIL" class="requiredemail" id="mce-EMAIL">
 </div>
  
  <input type="submit" value="Go" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
</form> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>


<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="container">
<div class="social">
  <div class="border col-lg-3"><img src="img/facebook.png"></div>
  <div class="border col-lg-3"><img src="img/instagram.png"></div>
  <div class="border col-lg-3"><img src="img/weibo.png"></div>
  <div class="border col-lg-3"><img src="img/wechat.png" ></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<p class="footer">About us</p>
<p class="footer">Terms of Service</p>
<p class="footer">Career</p>
<p class="footer">Contact us</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<p class="license">Copyright © 2016 Hangzhou Boru Network Technology Co. Ltd, All Rights Reserved - 浙ICP备15022282号-10</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>



   
  



 <!-- Chatra {literal} -->
<script>
    ChatraID = 'yxdSsZojbr259XBcX';
    (function(d, w, c) {
        var n = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0],
            s = d.createElement('script');
        w[c] = w[c] || function() {
            (w[c].q = w[c].q || []).push(arguments);
        };
        s.async = true;
        s.src = (d.location.protocol === 'https:' ? 'https:': 'http:')
            + '//call.chatra.io/chatra.js';
        n.parentNode.insertBefore(s, n);
    })(document, window, 'Chatra');
</script>
<!-- /Chatra {/literal} -->

<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/opaque.js"></script>  

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: share your code on jsfiddle or your working link.

Comment: @JeetDaloneboy http://120.25.106.212

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the with in

```
.requiredemail {
    //width: 261px;
}
```

it will solve your problem. you will find this css class tag in classic-10_7.css